# mockk verify after a delay

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

Whats the best way to `verify` after a delay?

For instance, I make a method call that calls `postDelayed` on some other object, and the call I want to verify happens in that `run()` block.

For instance, with Mockito, you can do the following:

```
verify(mock, after(100).atMost(5)).foo();

verify(mock, after(100).never()).bar();

verify(mock, after(200).atLeastOnce()).baz();
```

Is there an idiomatic or existing way with Mockk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy:

```
verify(timeout = 100, atMost = 5) { sum(1, 2) }

verify(timeout = 100, exactly = 0) { sum(1, 2) }

verify(timeout = 100, atLeast = 1) { sum(1, 2) }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: This seems to not be a full equivalent. If you put some bigger value than 100 (e.g. 1000), verify will not actually wait 1 second to verify.